# while loop inside other while loop, infinite loop

Tags: python

i want to parse a huge file consisting of thousands of blocks each of which contains several sub-blocks.for making it simple consider the the input file containing bellow lines:

```
a
2
3
4
b
3
9
2
c
7
```

each  on separate lines.where alphabets define each block and numbers are properties of the block,
 i want the output as a dictionary with block name as key and list of properties just 2 and 3 (if present) like this:

```
{a:[2,3],b:[3,2],c:[]}
```

i think the best way is using two while loops to read and search lines like this:

```
 dict={}
 with open('sample_basic.txt','r') as file:
     line=file.readline()
     line=line.strip()
     while line:
         if line.isalpha():
             block_name=line
             line=file.readline()
             line=line.strip()
             list=[]    
             while line:
                 lev_1=line
                 if lev_1 in ['2','3']:
                     list.append(lev_1)
                     line=file.readline()
                     line=line.strip()
                 if lev_1.isalpha():
                     dict[block_name]=list
                     break
                 else:
                     line=file.readline()
                     line=line.strip()
```

but it just goes to a infinite loop by execution.

i was looking for error but i cant find where it is.
i appreciate if anyone could give me some hint about it.

Comment: First, 'c\n'.isalpha() returns False because of the '\n', so you never put your list into your dictionary. You should do lev_1 = line.strip() or lev_1 = line[:-1] to remove the newline from the end of the lines. You can call str.isalpha() after that. Second, you call file.readline() twice in the second loop when line is 2 or 3 which makes the loop jump over some lines.

Comment: @SzieberthAdam i dont understand the second part of error, in the second loop i called file.readline() twice but each is in a separate 'if' statement so in each loop of second 'while' loop just one of them should be executed, why doesnt it happen? why python executes both of them?!

Comment: All consecutive ifs are executed. What you want to replace the second if with elif.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not check your code too closely, so I can not help you with the infinite loop, but I wrote new code without nested loops:

```
import collections
d = collections.defaultdict(list)
with open('sample_basic.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.isalpha():
            blockname=line
        else:
            if line in ('2', '3'):
                d[blockname].append(int(line))
```

The output using a file with the content you write is `{'b': [3, 2], 'a': [2, 3]}`.

If you want the empty list with the key `c` included in your dictionary do

```
d={}
with open('sample_basic.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.isalpha():
            blockname=line
            d[blockname] = []
        else:
            if line in ('2', '3'):
                d[blockname].append(int(line))
```

Comment: -1, even though this is a much better way than OP's method, here at stackoverflow we shouldn't just give out the complete code for others, but help them fix their code instead.

Comment: thanks for answers. definitely this is a better way.
but can someone help me to figure out about my mistakes. now my own code also gives result as {'a': ['2']}!. it seems that my code skip some lines although for each 'while' loop i think python should execute file.readline() just once!....what is wrong with this code!?